# Login / Logout via SecurityServiceProvider in Silex

Tags: authentication, routes, logout, silex

I have a problem with routing in SILEX.
I have a routing.yml

```
indexGet:
     path: /chat
     defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\StartApp::indexHtml' }
     methods: [GET]

indexPost:
     path: /chat
     defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\StartApp::sendMessage'}
     methods: [POST]

LoginGet:
     path: /login
     defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\Logins::checkLoginData'}
     methods: [GET]

RegisterGet:
     path: /register
     defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\RegisterForm::showReg'}
     methods: [GET]

RegisterPost:
     path: /register
     defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\RegisterForm::showReg'}
     methods: [POST]

Logout:
     path: /logout
     defaults: { _controller: 'resources\controller\Logout::logoutFromChat'}
     methods: [GET]
```

This is my FireWall config:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
        'chat' => array(
            'pattern'=>'/chat',
            'anonymous'=>false,
            //login_path: before authorisation  Check_path: path to check the date of the user
            'form'=>array('login_path'=>'/login','check_path' => '/chat/login_check'),
            //should realizise the logout
            'logout'=>array('logout_path'=>'/chat/logout','invalidate_session'=>true),
            'users'=> $app->share(function() use ($app){
                return new \resources\controller\UserProvider($app['db']);
            })
        )
 );
```

The problem is that the automatic routing for the login and the logout doesn't work. May you help me to find the failure?

Answer (score -1):

login and login_check should be outside of the firewall. currently only your login path is outside it.

Comment: As the [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html) says, `login_path` should be outside of the firewall, while `login_check` should be inside.